# JQuery or Javascript filter select options

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I'm developing an app that have a form that contains two selects populated dynamically with arrays.

The second select is disabled if there isn't a choice in the first of them and i need to filter the options of the second select respect the choice of the first.

Whereas I must to pass these values to another PHP page I mustn't do the filter using the value attribute.

I've tried to use a custom attribute but without results.

This is my code,

```
<tr>
    <td style="color: white;">Seleziona data: </td>
    <td>
        <select class="form-control" name="data" id="select1">
            <option value="prova" disabled selected> Scegli</option>
            <?php for ($y=0; $y<count($giorni); $y++){ $giorno=$ giorni[$y];?>
            <option value="<?php echo $giorno; ?>" id="<?php echo $y; ?>">
                <?php echo $giorno; ?> </option>
            <?php } ?>
        </select>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td style="color: white;">Seleziona ora: </td>
    <td>
        <select class="form-control" name="ora" id="select2" disabled>
            <?php $count=1 ; while ($count <=3 ){ if ($count==1 ){ for ($g=0; $g<count($ora1); $g++){ ?>
            <option id="<?php echo $count-1; ?>" value="<?php echo $ora1[$g]; ?>">
                <?php echo $ora1[$g]; ?>
            </option>
            <?php } $count ++; } ?>
            <?php if ($count==2 ){ for ($g=0; $g<count($ora2); $g++){ ?>
            <option id="<?php echo $count-1; ?>" value="<?php echo $ora2[$g]; ?>">
                <?php echo $ora2[$g]; ?>
            </option>
            <?php } $count ++; } ?>
            <?php if ($count==3 ){ for ($g=0; $g<count($ora2); $g++){ ?>
            <option id="<?php echo $count-1; ?>" value="<?php echo $ora3[$g]; ?>">
                <?php echo $ora3[$g]; ?>
            </option>
            <?php } $count ++; } } ?>
        </select>
      </td>
  </tr>
```

**JAVASCRIPT:**

```
<script>
    document.getElementById('select1').onchange = function() {
        document.getElementById('select2').disabled = false;
    };
</script>
<script>
    $("#select1").change(function() {
        if ($(this).data('options') == undefined) {
            /*Taking an array of all options-2 and kind of embedding it on the select1*/
            $(this).data('options', $('#select2 option').clone());
        }
        var id = $(this).id();
        var options = $(this).data('options').filter('[id=' + id + ']');
        $('#select2').html(options);
    });
</script>
```

How can I solve it?

Thanks

Comment: That's not JavaScript. Are you using jQuery?

Comment: yes, sorry.... do you know any solutions in Javascript? @user7393973

Comment: Could you try to explain the issue a little better? All I understood is, you have a `<select>` with dynamic options from an array which means it can vary. Then, depending of which is selected, you show the second `<select>` with dynamic `<option>`s according to which `<option>` has been selected in the first `<select>`. Did I got that right?

Comment: Please reframe the question pr explain it in a better way in the comment, as it is not clear wat you want to achieve

Answer (score 0):

There is an issue with your html. There is more than one option with an identical id. On a html document, ids must be unique.

For the same reason, you cannot filter your options on the `id` value.

What you should do is to use a `data-` attribute instead the `id` attribute. This will allow you to filter on it.

Comment: Thank's, so if i change my code changing id with data-id it should works?

Comment: If this is the only issue, then it will.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [json_encode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) function to generate JSON objects in your PHP code and create the select2 options dynamically on the client side.

```
<tr>
  <td style="color: white;">Seleziona data: </td>
  <td>
    <select class="form-control" name="data" id="select1">
      <option value="prova" disabled selected> Scegli</option>
<?php
  foreach ($giorni as $key => $value) {
?>
      <option value="<?php echo $value; ?>" id="<?php echo $key; ?>" ><?php echo $value; ?></option>
<?php
  }
?>
    </select>
  </td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td style="color: white;">Seleziona ora: </td>
  <td>
    <select class="form-control" name="ora" id="select2" disabled></select>
  </td>
</tr>

<script>
  // the options object contains the possible option values for select2
  // it can be accessed as an associative array using the selected value from select1
  var options = {
    "0" : <php echo json_encode($ora1, JSON_FORCE_OBJECT) ?>,
    "1" : <php echo json_encode($ora2, JSON_FORCE_OBJECT) ?>,
    "2" : <php echo json_encode($ora3, JSON_FORCE_OBJECT) ?>
  };

  // a helper variable to prevent unnecessary work
  var prevSelectedValue = null;

  // onChange handler for select1
  document.getElementById('select1').onchange = function () {
    var selectedValue = document.getElementById('select1').value;
    if (selectedValue && (prevSelectedValue != selectedValue)) {
      // select1 has changed so there is work to do
      // 1 - get a handle on select2 to make code more legible
      var select2 = document.getElementById('select2');
      // 2 - remove all existing options
      select2.options.length = 0;
      // 3 - add new options
      var obj = options[selectedValue];
      // iterate through the object to get the keys and values
      for (var key in obj) {
        if (obj.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
          var newOption = document.createElement('option');
          newOption.text = obj[key];
          newOption.value = key;
          select2.options.add(newOption);
        }
      }
      // 4 - enable select2
      select2.disabled = false;
      // 5 - record select1 change in prevSelectedValue
      prevSelectedValue = selectedValue;
    }
  };
</script>
```

Comment: with your code the second select is always disabled

Comment: No it isn't. The line `select2.disabled = false;` at the end of the if condition enables the control. See https://jsfiddle.net/opm7hknd/